# Linux: how to move each file into a correspondingly named folder

Tags: linux, shell

I have a small but interesting task here. I have a list of files with same extension, for ex.

```
a.abc
b.abc
c.abc
```

What I want here is to first create folders called `a`, `b`, `c`... for each `.abc` file, and then move each one into its folder.

I was able to get the first step done pretty straightforwardly using a cmd line `find ... | sed ... | xargs mkdir...`, but when I tried to use a similar cmd to move each file into its own folder, I couldn't find the answer.

I'm not fluent with the cmd here, and I have a very fuzzy memory that in `find` cmd I can use some kind of back reference to reuse the file/directory name, did I remember it wrong? Searched it up but couldn't find a good reference.

Can anyone help me to complete the cmd here?

Thanks.

Comment: Good reference: [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find). You can also view it in your shell by saying `man find`.

Comment: if directory already exist, just use rename command .. i guess `rename 's@((.*).abc)@$2/$1@' *` should do the trick.`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's your one liner

```
find . -name "*.abc" -exec sh -c 'NEWDIR=`basename "$1" .abc` ; mkdir "$NEWDIR" ; mv "$1" "$NEWDIR" ' _ {} \;
```

or alternatively

```
find . -name "*.abc" -exec sh -c 'mkdir "${1%.*}" ; mv "$1" "${1%.*}" ' _ {} \;
```

And [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) is a better guide at using `find` than the man page.

[This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) page explains the parameter expansion that is going on (to understand the `${1%.*}`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `find` and `xargs` solution which handles filenames with spaces:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -l sh -c 'mkdir "${1%.*}" && mv "$1" "${1%.*}"' sh
```

Note that it does not support filenames with newlines and/or shell-expandable characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
for F in /tmp/folder/*.abc # replace by $1 for first arg
do
   BASE="${F%.abc}"
   mv "$F" "$BASE"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess with a script this should be pretty simple. But I'm just curious whether a one line solution with find cmd can work. Of course you can put a short script after find also.